# Do the Google App Engine OAuth endpoints support OAuth 2.0?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

Do the OAuth endpoints provided by Google App Engine (eg https://app-id.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken) support OAuth 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from recent ikai blog post about [Setting up an oauth provider on Google App Engine](http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/):

> As of the time of this writing, App
>   Engine only supports OAuth 1.0.

Comment: @proppy, Hi just want to enquire if oAuth 2.0 supports is in the works for app engine. I could not find any information on that yet.

Comment: @Udbhav you can sign up for Google Cloud Endpoint here: http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/